# Cinnamon Getting rid of CTRL-ALT-A shortcut

Tags: cinnamon

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with default Cinnamon 3.6.7.
I'm using emacs and when I press CTRL-ALT-A, Cinnamon hijacks the keys and does something weird with my terminals.

It bring them all on my current workspace, but there are also some blank ones without anything inside. Pressing again CTRL-ALT-A makes them all disappear.

I can't find what is responsible for this behavior: I've looked into Keyboard/Shortcuts, looked into Cinnamon's code on github without any luck.

Comment: Could you bother explaining why the question is downvoted ?

Comment: Did you find out what's happening? I'm searching for this and cannot find anything.

Comment: Nope, still stuck on this issue

Comment: Probably not an answer for you but I've udpated Linux Mint from 19 to 19.1 and the problem is gone. Cinnamon 4.6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this issue on a brand new Linux Mint 19.1 install, I searched all possible system keybindings, to no avail - then, I found out that Ctrl-Alt-A was hijacked by Terminator, even if it was set to use Ctrl-Shift-Alt-A. Re-configuring Terminator to use a different shortcut and then restarting it did the job.

Comment: DAMN, that was it. I'm using terminator also but I really thought it was a Cinnamon issue. I completely disabled the the shortcut